# Trying to migrate d3 v3 map to d3 v5 map using Promise

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to migrate a map created with d3.js version 3 to version 5. But, version 5 uses promises and I'm not sure how to change the d3.json method to use a promise. How do I change my existing v3 code to use the v5 promises? Thank you.

Original d3.json method I'm using:

```
d3.json("ne_50m_admin_0_countries_simplified.json", function(json) {
                
                //Bind data and create one path per GeoJSON feature
                svg.selectAll("path")
                   .data(json.features)
                   .enter()
                   .append("path")
                   .attr("d", path)
                   .attr("stroke", "rgba(8, 81, 156, 0.2)")
                   .attr("fill", "rgba(8, 81, 156, 0.6)");
        
            });
```

Trying to change it to leverage the new promise way of calling d3.json. Does not produce map.

```
d3.json("ne_50m_admin_0_countries_simplified.json").then(data => {
                svg.selectAll("path")
                   .data(json.features)
                   .enter()
                   .append("path")
                   .attr("d", path)
                   .attr("stroke", "rgba(8, 81, 156, 0.2)")
                   .attr("fill", "rgba(8, 81, 156, 0.6)");
});
```

Comment: If the parameter inside `then` is called `data`, it should be `.data(data.features)`, not `.data(json.features)`. Voting to close as *typo*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are using 'data' as your variable name instead of 'json' in the callback function.

try

```
d3.json("ne_50m_admin_0_countries_simplified.json").then(json => {
                svg.selectAll("path")
                   .data(json.features)
                   .enter()
                   .append("path")
                   .attr("d", path)
                   .attr("stroke", "rgba(8, 81, 156, 0.2)")
                   .attr("fill", "rgba(8, 81, 156, 0.6)");
});
```